# Max if statement

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2010

I am using the below formula. I'm convinced I am doing it right but its not giving me the results that it should.

```
=MAX(IF(Sickness!D:D=Sheet3!A2,Sickness!H:H))
```

and

```
{=MAX(IF(Sickness!D:D=Sheet3!A2,Sickness!H:H))}
```

Sickness!D:D shows advisor names, and Sickness!H:H shows the dates they returned to work - The results show as either 00/01/1900 so presume these are for people who are not listed in the spreadsheet.

And other people seem to have random dates listed against there name.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's exactly the problem - here's a little handler:

```
=IF(COUNTIF(Sickness!D:D,Sheet3!A2)>0,MAX(IF(Sickness!D:D=Sheet3!A2,Sickness!H:H)),"Not listed")
```

Comment: Thank you. Getting there - Its correctly showing Not Listed for the correct individuals. The ones that should show dates all show 00/01/1900

Comment: I forgot to add the array - Thank you so much